# How to keep widget state while switching between widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-state

I'm developing a web app, where I'm trying to add a chat screen. I'm trying to use the `floatingActionButton` parameter and witching between `FloatingActionButton` and the `ChatRoom` and the user presses the `FloatingActionButton`.

The flow of the ChatRoom,

> User taps on FloatingActionButton and opens ChatRoom

> On Logingin to ChatRoom and user sees the ChatScreen

> User closes the ChatRoom

> On Reopening the ChatRoom user is again shown the validation screen

When I wasn't using this switching, ChatRoom maintained its state and on reopening, it showed the user the `ChatScreen` as expected.

**Code**

```
GetBuilder<HomeController>(
          id: 'updateChatRoomContainer',
          builder: (_controller) {
            return AnimatedContainer(
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              width: _controller.chatRoomWidth,
              height: _controller.chatRoomHeight,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
              child: GetBuilder<ThemeController>(builder: (_themeController) {
                return _controller.chatRoomOpen
                    ? Stack(
                          children: [
                            ChatRoom(),
                            ChatRoomActions(_controller)
                          ],
                    )
                    : IconButton(
                        onPressed: _controller.toggleChatRoom,
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.chat,
                        ),
                      );
              }),
            );
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps look into using `PageView` and switch between different indexes. That will maintain your state for you.

Comment: I needed a stack there, not sure how would I replace that with `PageView`. Nevertheless, I have changed the logic in my statemanamgent controller that allowed me to achieve it.